# Codeigniter One to many relationship data display

Tags: php, codeigniter, crud

I am working on a project, In this project i have to display one category name and subjects which related to particular category. One side is category table and many side was the subject table. I have written a code which join tables and give me some array of data. But i'm stuck at showing that result, here my result i got

```
Array
    (
        [id_category] => 9
        [cat_name] => OL
        [tbl_subject] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id_subject] => 13
                        [name] => Science
                        [description] => සාමාන්‍ය පෙළ විද්‍යාව
                        [id_category_fk] => 9
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id_subject] => 14
                        [name] => Agri & Food technology
                        [description] => කෘෂි හා ආහාර තාක්ෂණය
                        [id_category_fk] => 9
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [id_subject] => 31
                        [name] => Business & Accounting
                        [description] => 
                        [id_category_fk] => 9
                    )

            )

    )
    1
    Array
    (
        [id_category] => 16
        [cat_name] => Grade 06
        [tbl_subject] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id_subject] => 15
                        [name] => Science
                        [description] => විද්‍යාව
                        [id_category_fk] => 16
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id_subject] => 32
                        [name] => Sinhala
                        [description] => සිංහල භාෂාව හා සාහිත්‍යය
                        [id_category_fk] => 16
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [id_subject] => 33
                        [name] => Geography
                        [description] => භූගෝල විද්‍යාව
                        [id_category_fk] => 16
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [id_subject] => 34
                        [name] => Buddhism
                        [description] => බුද්ධ ධර්මය
                        [id_category_fk] => 16
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [id_subject] => 36
                        [name] => Citizan Education
                        [description] => පුරවැසි අධ්‍යාපනය
                        [id_category_fk] => 16
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [id_subject] => 52
                        [name] => Geography English medium
                        [description] => 
                        [id_category_fk] => 16
                    )

            )

    )
    1
```

This type of array. 
I have problem with display it within a list
Here is my dummy list which i wish to populating with results data

```
<div class="col-4 mb-4">
      <h3> Category Name</h3>
      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush exam-list">
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
         Subject name <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">14</span></li>
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
         Subject name <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">14</span></li>
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
         Subject name <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">14</span></li>
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
         Subject name  <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">14</span></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my code section in my model class

```
public function getAllExamPapers()
{
  // get distinct item of category table and join table with subject table
  $this->db->distinct();
  $this->db->select('tbl_category.id_category,tbl_category.name AS cat_name');
  $this->db->join('tbl_subject', 'tbl_category.id_category = tbl_subject.id_category_fk');
  $results = $this->db->get('tbl_category')->result_array();

  // Loop through the tbl_category array
  foreach ($results as $i => $result) {
    // Get an array of subject
    // 'id_category_fk' is the foreign_key in the tbl_subject table
    $this->db->where('id_category_fk', $result['id_category']);
    $sub_query = $this->db->get('tbl_subject')->result_array();

    // Add the subject array to the array entry for this category
    $results[$i]['tbl_subject'] = $sub_query;

  }
  return $results;
}
```

There is easy way to archive this? or give me suggestion to easily figure out this problem here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try your loop array using this

```
foreach($results as $result){ 
   echo '<h3>'.$result['cat_name'].'</h3>'
   echo '<ul>';
     foreach($result['tbl_subject'] as $subject){
         echo '<li>'.$subject['name'].'</li>';
     }
   echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: Nice.. You can improve the code as you need. I'm Sorry not type all code.

Comment: No that is cool, i know how to implement it, if i merge one more table here assume papers which related to one subject (i need take how many papers have for one subject) then how to change this exist code? because i have to mention count of papers inside bootstrap badge for each subject